# Top 3 value from each group in scala lists

Tags: scala

I am new to the Scala language.

I am having two Scala lists `emp(empid, deptid, empname, salary)` and `dept(deptname, deptid)`.

I want to find out the top 3 salaries in each department.

```
val emp =
   List(
      (1,"10","Smith",3000),
      (1,"10","Smith",3000),
      (3,"10","Williams",1000),
      (4,"10","Jones",2000),
      (5,"10","Brown",5000),
      (6,"20","Brown",8000),
      (7,"10","Jones",11000),
      (8,"20","Brown",5000),
      (9,"20","Brown",8000)
   )

val dept = 
  List(
      ("Finance","10"),
      ("Marketing","20")
  )
```

The output should have top 3 salaries from `Finance` and top 3 from `Marketing`. Help me resolve this without using spark functions.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So, I will help you with the algorithm but you have to figure out the code. Use `groupMap` in the `emp` list to get all salaries of a department, then use `.view.mapValues` on the result to sort the list and then try to take the first three elements. Finally, convert the `dept` list into a map and use that to do a final `map` on the previous result to get the department name from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readability and conciseness, you should model the `emp` `List` to a `List` of a `case class Persona`. Then you can intuitively figure out the rest of the code. You can model the `dept` `List` in a similar manner as well if it becomes too big and hard to manage, but for this particular example I left it as is.

You could use `groupBy` to create a `Map` of `deptId -> List[Persona]` , then sort it by salaries, take only the first `n` salaries that you are interested in, and process the list to have it match the exact output that you need.

By the way, I recommend `deptId` to be an `Int`, just like the `id` of a `Persona`.

Here's the code:

```
object Program extends App {

  val emp = List(
    (1, "10", "Smith", 3000),
    (1, "10", "Smith", 3000),
    (3, "10", "Williams", 1000),
    (4, "10", "Jones", 2000),
    (5, "10", "Brown", 5000),
    (6, "20", "Brown", 8000),
    (7, "10", "Jones", 11000),
    (8, "20", "Brown", 5000),
    (9, "20", "Brown", 8000)
  )

  val dept = List(
    ("Finance", "10"),
    ("Marketing", "20")
  )

  case class Persona(id: Int, deptId: String, name: String, sal: Int)

  val personas = emp.map { case (id, deptId, name, sal) =>
    Persona(id, deptId, name, sal)
  }

  val myMap: Map[String, List[Persona]] = personas.groupBy(_.deptId)

  def topNSalariesGroupedBy(n: Int, deptId: String): String =
    myMap(deptId).sortWith(_.sal > _.sal).take(n).map(_.sal).mkString(", ")

  val n = 3
  dept.foreach(dept =>
    println(
      s"Top $n salaries from department ${dept._1} are: ${topNSalariesGroupedBy(n, dept._2)}"
    )
  )

}
```

Output:

```
Top 3 salaries from department Finance are: 11000, 5000, 3000
Top 3 salaries from department Marketing are: 8000, 8000, 5000
```